# Action bar Sherlok with sliding menu?

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I want to show the slidemenu through the action bar sherlok 
when the top left bar clicked it shows the slidemenu .
I do everything but i cant make event to show the slide menu from the top left corner 
i do the following but its not working

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
       {        
          case android.R.id.home:            
            SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
            menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setBehindOffset(100);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_menu);
              break;

       }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

- Create the SlidingMenu inside `onCreate()` and not in `onOptionsItemSelected()`.
- In onOptionsItemSelected you can toggle the sliding menu like this:
  `getSlidingMenu().toggle();`

Full example:

```
private SlidingMenu menu;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        // more initialization code
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
       {        
          case android.R.id.home:            
           menu.toggle();
           return true;
       }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: i implement the SherlockActivity and i cant use this code 
'getSlidingMenu().toggle();'
how can i use it ?

Comment: Make `menu` a private field in your class and try calling `menu.toggle()`.

Comment: I cant found menu.toggle(); @Nachi

Comment: I also get a NullPointerException when calling getSlidingMenu().toggle();